# P/Invoke wrong parameters being passed to C library function

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I have been trying to call the NewPixelRegionIterator function in ImageMagick's library from C# code and have been running into a parameter passing problem.
More specifically, here is the definition of NewPixelRegionIterator:

```
PixelIterator NewPixelRegionIterator(MagickWand *wand,const ssize_t x,
const ssize_t y,const size_t width,const size_t height)
```

And here is the code that imports this function into C# code:

```
[DllImport("libMagickWandDev.so")]
internal static extern PixelIterator NewPixelRegionIterator(IntPtr MagickWand,  
          IntPtr left, IntPtr top, UIntPtr width, UIntPtr height);
```

The fact that I import **libMagickWandDev.so** and not **libMagickWand.so** is because libMagickWandDev.so is compiled with debugging support enabled, so that I could run mono with gdb to know if the problem was in the call to the C function (and in fact it was).

The problem, found through gdb, is that when calling NewPixelRegionIterator such as:

```
PixelIterator PixIt = PixelIteratorImports.NewPixelRegionIterator(MagickWandPtr,  
         new IntPtr(x), new IntPtr(y), new UIntPtr(1), new UIntPtr(1));
```

The actual parameters that are passed, found via gdb, are:

```
Breakpoint 1, NewPixelRegionIterator (wand=0x7fffffffc7a8, x=10744336, y=5, 
width=6, height=1) at wand/pixel-iterator.c:418
```

- 5 and 6 are good, these are the actual numbers passed to the function (although *x* should be equal to 5 and *y* should equal 6, making *width* and *height* both equal to 1). This means that the order of the parameters is sort of shifted to the right, and that 0x7fffffffc7a8 is probably part of the struct to be returned or something else.
- If it helps, *10744336* is the value of *MagickWandPtr* (the address of the Magick Wand), because setting the *wand* parameter to this and *x* to a sane value while in gdb makes the function run just fine.
- PixelIterator is a struct that was mapped very carefully (I have also verified that the size of the struct through Marshal.SizeOf and actual C code's sizeof() are the same 4192 bytes)

Once again, thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the calling convetion the C api uses. Your most likely options are Cdecl or stdcall. The default for the DllImportAttribute is WinApi which will default to stcall on anything but Win CE.

Comment: Are you sure you can just return a struct from a PInvoke-function? Don't you need to return it using out parameters/pointers?

Comment: I would guess that part of the problem is the width of `size_t`... it's probably 32 bits, but you're passing IntPtr, which will be 64 bits on a 64-bit system.  (Also, why are you using UIntPtr for some parameters and IntPtr for others?)  But come to think of it, the values are getting pushed to the right, so perhaps you're calling a 32-bit function with 64-bit pointers?  Try running the whole thing in a 32-bit process.

Comment: Thanks @user957902, I'm on linux with Mono, and both Cdecl and StdCall still have not worked.

Comment: @phoog I have written a C program that prints sizeof(size_t) and sizeof(ssize_t), and they are both 8 bytes long in my machine. Also, ssize_it is signed and size_t is unsigned, and that is why I use the analog types in C# (although I could care less, since these values are usually very small). I compiled ImageMagick in a 64-bit machine and therefore I expect it to be a 64-bit library, although it could not be. I will try running my program in 32-bit mode now.

Comment: @usr The problem honestly never crossed my mind.. what could I do to solve this?

Comment: @MarceloZabani aha, I didn't notice the extra s in `ssize_t`.  If you've measured those, and they're 8 bytes, then don't waste your time trying 32-bit mode.  Other evidence against my hypothesis would be that the arguments `5` and `6` are both shifted by one position only.  I think usr's answer probably the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you can just return a struct from a PInvoke-function? Don't you need to return it using out parameters/pointers?

Because the parameters are shifted I'd expect a hidden parameter of type PixelIterator* as the first or the last parameter. And a return-type of void. This is how C compilers implement a struct-returning function under the hood.

In the comments you explained that returning a PixelIterator* solves the problem. The reason for that is probably that the C function is allocating an object and returning its pointer. The definition did not give a clue to that, though... Anyway, you probably need to free that memory when you are done with the object returned.

Comment: I did not know the behavior of C compilers in respect to that. I have changed my import code to include a "out IntPtr ReturnValue" as the first parameter and to be of void return type, but The parameters are still passed incorrectly. Do you know of a source that explains in further detail how this could be done?

Comment: Did you try adding this param as the last param? Also try to add 1-2 padding params both at the beginning and at the end of the list.

Comment: Still following your thoughts on the C function actually returning a pointer, I thought maybe I whould just give my imported method a IntPtr return type, without including any further parameters. And it seems like you were right! After converting the value pointed to by the pointer to a struct, I have successfully accessed its members.. If you could only edit your answer a bit, I'll give the right answer to you.